# Casework on Cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Three cards are dealt at random from a standard deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that the first card is a 4, the second card is a $\clubsuit$, and the third card is a 2?

Is there an efficient way to do this with cases? If so, how? Is there any other way to do this problem without cases?

So for the 4 is club and 2 is club case I have 1/52 * 11/51*1/50.

For the 4 is club and 2 is not club case I have 1/52*12/51* 3/50.

For the 4 is not club and 2 is club case I have 3/52 * 12/51 * 1/50.

For the 4 is not club and 2 is not club case I have 3/52 * 13/51*1/50.

My final answer is 122/132600 = 61/66300. Why am I wrong?

Comment: The cases are based on whether the $4$ is a club or not and whether the 2 is a club or not.  It is probably the quickest way

Comment: Ok. So I only need four cases then. @Henry?

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment.  Yes, if $4$ is not a club, then there are still $13$ clubs that could be selected in your second draw, so the probability in your third case should be $\frac{3}{52} \cdot \frac{13}{51} \cdot \frac{1}{50}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That was where I went wrong.